# Styling Buttons in IOS Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am new to IOS development. In windows phone development we use to define a style(appearance e.g) of the button control in app Global place and just use that style anywhere on any button in the app by assigning the style property.

Is there anything similar in IOS XCode? I know I can customize the button in the property and appearance windows in XCode. But in this way I have to give style to each and every similar button in the app. and if there is any change I have to change it everywhere. What IOS developers do in these kind situations?

Comment: You can subclass UIButton. And when your need a button, write `var myButton = MyCustomButton()` instead of `var myButton = UIButton()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to style *all* buttons in your app in a standard way, then you would style the appearance proxy for `UIButton`. You get one by calling the class method `UIButton.appearance()`, and then styling the returned value the way you want your buttons to look. You can also do a more fine-grained appearance by calling methods like `UIButton.appearanceWhenContainedIn()`.

Comment: this is neat. is there any way of doing this from the Xcode UI rather than programmatically? I want to style one button, and then somehow make its styling some kind of reusable 'class' (as in CSS class).

Comment: Sadly, no, at least no built-in way. You could load a view from a xib and use its properties to set the app-wide appearance proxy for its class.

Answer (score 3):

Create a UIButton subclass.
For example for creating a UIButton with rounded corners and a border:

Header file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYRoundedCornerButton : UIButton
@end
```

Implementation file

```
...import headers etc...
@implementation XYRoundedCornerButton

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.borderRadius = 1.0f;
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using storyboard, You don't need to add any code in class.
Just drag one button and set all the properties you want, whether background colour, corner radius etc, whatever you want. And then either copy it and paste wherever you want or select the button, ALT+DRAG it .

Comment: This is bad for the lack of ability of adjusting all buttons at the same time after they are created.